# Importing Math.PI as reference or value

Tags: java, math, import, static, pi

I'm preparing for a basic certification in Java.

I'm a little confused by the answer to a question that I have got right(!):-

Given:

```
 public class Circle {
     static double getCircumference(double radius ) {
          return PI * 2 * radius;
     }
     public static double getArea(double radius) {
          return PI * radius * radius;
     }
}
```

Which import statement will enable the code to compile and run?

```
import java.lang.*;

import static java.lang.Math.PI;

import java.lang.Math.*;

import java.lang.Math;
```

I answered import static java.lang.Math.PI;

BUT the explanation of two other options below confuses me:-

The statements import java.lang.Math; and import java.lang.Math.*; will not enable the code to compile and run. These import statements will only allow Math.PI as a reference to the PI constant.

My question is: what would be wrong with the import statements only allowing a reference to the PI constant? Would the value be uninitialized and zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Allow Math.PI as a reference to the PI constant' means that your code will have to look like this in order to work:

```
static double getCircumference(double radius ) {
      return Math.PI * 2 * radius;
 }
 public static double getArea(double radius) {
      return Math.PI * radius * radius;
 }
```

What `import java.lang.Math;` does is importing the class `java.lang.Math` so you can reference it with `Math` instead of the qualified version `java.lang.Math`. `import java.lang.Math.*;` does the same for `Math` and all nested classes, but not it's members.

Answer (score 6):

This

```
import java.lang.Math.*;
```

imports all (accessible) types declared within `Math`.

This

```
import java.lang.Math;
```

is redundant because `Math` is part of `java.lang` which is imported by default.

Both will require that you use

```
Math.PI
```

to access the field.

This

```
import static java.lang.Math.PI;
```

imports the `static` member `Math.PI` so that you can use its simple name in your source code.